# Auto update your applications through Windows Update

Tags: .net, auto-update

Here is a scenario: User installs .NET application that you have made. After some time, you find a security issue in it and create a patch for it. When patch is ready, you post it "somewhere", and when next Windows update is run on user's machine (automatically or manually), that application is updated, too. I'm wondering if this is possible...and how? Searching on MSDN about it, didn't give any results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check out Microsoft [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [BITS](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sharpBITS.aspx?fid=321911&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=2947694) downloader that Microsoft Update uses to download the files in the background.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't, unless it's a hardware driver which has gone through MS certification and is published on Microsoft update. The MS update web site is closed and limited to MS software and some hardware partners.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that via Microsoft Update, but you could check out how [Paint .NET](http://www.getpaint.net/) or .[NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) implemented their auto-update feature.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the Windows Update feature is only for Microsoft supplied software and updates

Answer (score 0):

Windows Update is only for Microsoft products. You can't host your software on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, as others said. You can build your own updater, as many companys does.